# Flyway Gradle Plugin with Cloud Spanner - No database found to handle url

Tags: flyway, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to setup Flyway for Google Cloud Spanner (beta) using the flyway gradle plugin but it gets the error below when executing `./gradlew flywayinfo`.

```
> Error occured while executing flywayInfo
  No database found to handle jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/<my-project>/instances/<my-instance>/databases/<my-db>
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
 id 'java'
 id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '7.13.0'
}

...

dependencies {
 implementation(
  'org.flywaydb:flyway-gcp-spanner:7.13.0-beta'
 )
}

flyway {
 url = 'jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/<my-project>/instances/<my-instance>/databases/<my-db>'
}
```

The values in the url correspond to my project and instance names.

I've also tried:

- using a service account key in the end of the URL
- adding the `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner-jdbc:2.3.2` JDBC driver dependency (implementation)
- I'm behind a proxy but I have set it in my `gradle.properties` with `systemProp.http.proxyHost` and `systemProp.http.proxyPort` (also for https)

Using Flyway CLI and the API programmatically works.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the error comes from flyway implementation [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/c36800d6c565a564e93e32cbf58c0a4b1040cfa8/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/DatabaseTypeRegister.java#L82). Your issue seems somewhat similar with https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3028.

Consider opening a new issue here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues